# Unknown Crash Reason

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I got this crash:

```
"this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view."
```

And I have no idea what its talking about.  Could someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha. I was doing custom cells and I put the normal ViewController instead of the CellViewController on this line:

```
        NSArray * array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhoneFavoritesCellViewController" owner:nil options:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know what object this message coming from. Look at the beginning of the line and find the part that starts with `0x` then pause the app in the debugger and type `po` followed by whatever number started with `0x` (including `0x`). That should give you a starting point.
Also, if you have a lot of classes in your project add an `NSLog()` to the designated initializers and the nib start-up methods (`awakeFromNib`, `windowControllerDidLoadNib`, etc). This can also help you figure out who is making all the noise.
Once you have a few more details if you are still stuck then edit your question, as it is now we can say is that you have a `view` connection to something that doesn't have a `view` property.

Answer (score 0):

Open your nib in Interface Builder and check that there are no warnings showing up on the document. It sounds like you have something connected to "view" on a class that doesn't support the view connection.

Alternatively, if you have a view controller, is it declared as a UIViewController subclass?

Comment: Well, its a no on the first suggestion, once I got rid of the View Connection there was a new crash error about that.  So that part doesn't help.